# How can one quickly paste content of the clipboard to a variable in the Chrome Dev Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I know I can easily *copy* the value of any variable from the **Chrome Dev Console** by running:

```
copy(variable_in_current_context1);
```

Is there a reverse method to *set* the value of any variable from the clipboard?

I often deal with large pieces of text that I need to set variables to during debug. These texts are full of characters that need to be escaped/replaced if pasted directly into console as text. So this way is too painful for such cases.

*Pseudo-code* I imagine:

```
variable_in_current_context2 = paste();
```

Answer (score 1):

No, as far as I'm aware of.
The full console API could be found here:
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/utilities

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking of some undocumented/experimental feature to try. Searching the internet gave me nothing.